# How to keep a container running in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

We are deploying an application in ECS, which is exiting due to some error.
We need to log in to the container and check the logs, however the container stops when the application exits after the error.

How can I keep the container running so that I can ssh in to it?

I tried using `tail -f /dev/null` in the `startup.sh` script, which is run at the container startup.

I need to run the startup.sh script to configure the SSH, etc.
However, it looks like executing `tail -f /dev/null` at the end of the scripts does not seem to keep the container running.

Appreciate any advice on how to keep an ECS container running.

Comment: Did you configure your ecs task to log into cloudwatch?

Comment: Yes, but the app log is on a different file, which I need to check.

Comment: I would fix your app log so it goes to CloudWatch instead of trying to hack around to keep the container running somehow.